# Get Javac to pick up my Class

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

**Background to the Problem:**
Make a java file containing a class with a super class that does not exist; get javac to parse the class, but not compile it; programatically produce the super class (that means without a class file); and finally let javac produce successfully a class file.

Here is CompilerAPITest.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;    
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

/**
* A test class to test dynamic compilation API.
*
*/
public class CompilerAPITest {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CompilerAPITest.class.getName()) ;

    public void doCompilation (){
        File[] files = {new File("/home/guestu/GeneratedClass.java")};

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), null);
        /* Prepare a list of compilation units (java source code file objects) to input to  compilation task*/
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = stdFileManager.getJavaFileObjects(files);

        /*Create a diagnostic controller, which holds the compilation problems*/
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
        /*Create a compilation task from compiler by passing in the required input objects prepared above*/
        CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, stdFileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits) ;

        boolean status = compilerTask.call();
        if (!status){//If compilation error occurs
            /*Iterate through each compilation problem and print it*/
            for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
                System.out.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
            } 
    }
    try {
       stdFileManager.close() ;//Close the file manager
    } catch (IOException e) {
 }

//Here is Helloworld.java
public class Helloworld extends GeneratedClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }

}

//And here is GeneratedClass.java
package com.sun.tools.javac.parser;

import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Flags;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCAnnotation;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCClassDecl;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCCompilationUnit;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCExpression;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCModifiers;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCTypeParameter;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.ListBuffer;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Names;

/* This class programmatically produces the superclass "GeneratedClass" with signature public class GeneratedClass{} */

public class GeneratedClass {
    TreeMaker maker;
    Names names;
    public GeneratedClass(ParserFactory fac) {
        maker = fac. F;
        names = fac.names;
    }

    public JCCompilationUnit getTree() {
        ListBuffer<JCTree> defs = new ListBuffer<JCTree>();
        defs.append(makeClassDecl());
        return maker.TopLevel(List.<JCAnnotation>nil(), null, defs.toList());
    }

    /* This is a class decalaration node for public class GeneratedClass{}*/
    protected JCClassDecl makeClassDecl() {
        JCModifiers mods = maker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC);
        Name name = names.fromString("GeneratedClass");
        return maker.ClassDef(mods, name, List.<JCTypeParameter>nil(), null, List.<JCExpression>nil(), List.<JCTree>nil());
    }
}
```

**My Current Challenge**

I have programmatically generated a class file (GeneratedClass).  I would like it to get picked up by the java compiler to compile Helloworld.java.  I have tried the above method but Helloworld does not compile because it cant pick up GeneratedClass.  Is there a way this can be done?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to customize the file manager. But your task seems to be perfectly suited for an annotation processor. The code will be parsed and it is totally fine if some classes are missing. A model of the parsed code get's passed to to the annotation processor, which can do whatever chooses to. There is even some infrastructure for writing generated classes. See

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html

and

http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/